# Looking for Lexmark X422 MFP scanner software

Tags: windows-xp, scanner, lexmark-printer

I've got a Lexmark X422 printer and I'd like to use it on my computer as a scanner (it is installed locally).

Currently, I can scan in pages via Photoshop, but I'd like to use a more specific scanner software so that I can scan multiple pages at once and have them be put into one document. Or if there is a way to do this in Photoshop that would work, too.

I can't seem to find any free software that will support the x422 and allow me to scan multiple pages.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of free products that may do the job :

[Scan2PDF](http://www.koma-code.de/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=39&Itemid=82)
[Documalis Free Scanner](http://www.documalis.com/free/us_documalis_free_scanner.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Not free (comes bundled with MANY scanners though), but does exactly what you want (scan many pages in, and then let you stack them into single documents) and then some, is [Nuance's PaperPort](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-product/paperport/standard/index.htm):

> PaperPort 14 enhances the capabilities of your scanner or all-in-one
>   device to quickly transform paper — mail, photos, legal paperwork, tax
>   information, forms, bills, receipts warranties, and other important
>   documents — into high-quality, searchable PDF files with the click of
>   a button.

It will support virtually any scanner that works with Windows WIA, or a TWAIN driver.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) it's hands down the best scanning software available. I found it through one of my vendors (remotescan) who use it exclusively for testing since it seems to work with just about any scanner/driver combination (WIA or TWAIN).

Comment: Will it allow me to scan multiple pages to one document?

Comment: Yes but if you go into batch scanning it has this option.